# Using DSolve for r(t) y'(t) = y(t) r'(t)

Tags: differential-equations

I am fairly new to Mathematica and I was trying to solve this equation 
r(t) y'(t) = y(t) r'(t) using DSolve. How can I adapt it to the DSolve function formalism?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the equation as

```
DSolve[r[t] y'[t] == y[t] r'[t], y[t], t]
```

works, yielding,

```
{{y[t] -> C[1] r[t]}}
```

as it should.

Comment: You are most welcome.  Please accept the answer, if it meets your need.  Best wishes.